# How to configure Sophos UTM to mask an internal ip with a DNS name

Tags: networking, router, dns, sophos

I have a CRM software which runs on Apache on a separated network at a 10.10.10.10 ip while my local network is at 192.168.1.0 range.

I also have 10.10.1.0 range for VPNs which are only can connect to the 10.10.10.10 computer. I'm trying to add a dns name as example.dns for that computer which is 10.10.10.10.

At the computer 10.10.10.10 changed the hosts file as example.dns localhost and it's works on that computer but not everywhere else.

I tried to add in sophos utm at dns entries however it not worked.

FYI the 10.10.10.10 computer does not have access to the internet and my network. Can somebody explain it how can I do it ?

Comment: Is the Sophos UTM the DNS server for your network?

Comment: no. I have a domain controller in the 192.168.1.0 network. Assuming from your question I need to configure my dns server to redirect it?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand that question Zsolt - could you try rephrasing it?

Answer (score 0):

The 10.10.10.10 server needs routing table entries to figure out how to contact the 192.168.1.0 network. If you're also using the 192.168.1.0 gateway for internet access, you need to tell the 10.10.10.10 server to use that gateway, too.

The DNS entries should come from the DNS server you're using, not the HOSTS file. That way you only have to update the entry in one place; otherwise, you will have to edit each client that tries to connect to the 10.10.10.10 server.

Answer (score -1):

if just for a few hosts, so go to network protection, network definitions, add a entry for that hosts, with type host and fill out IP adress and dns name (whatever you want) at advanced settings.

if you'll need resolving ip to name for a whole network, where a server on your network host's the dns entries, so go to interfaces and routing, dns, request dns, and make an entry as eg. for a network 192.168.1.0, name it 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa  then add the dns server or server's with is hosting the ptr entries. Now you have names on your utm :-)